# SQL Can I have one result table from two queries so they align data in different columns

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL table with 9 columns:

```
TSTAMP  SYSTEM  MODE    BOARD   CHANNEL USED    TOTAL   BOARDID STATUS
```

The "SYSTEM" contains a value of 1 - 3.

The first query will look for System matching 1 and Channel count and Used max and Status <> free.

- Then again for System matching 2 etc
- Then again for System matching 3

I would like to (this is usage by hour (24 hour format)) data laid out in columns with the 24 hours in column 1 descending in rows.

I know I can do each query individually but being new to SQL not sure what command to make the result table line up the way I like.

The result I'm trying for looks basically like this:

```
Telematic 1 Hour    Processed   MaxUsed Telematic 2 Hour    Processed   MaxUsed Telmatic 3  Hour    Processed   MaxUsed
    1   10  585 17  2   10  583 16  3   10  584 15
    1    4    8  1  2    4   14  2  3    4    8  1
```

Sorry for the wrap around.

I can use UNION but that just create 4 columns. Not the 12 I'm looking for.

Comment: Here is my current query (i'm only showing 2 request):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear where you are getting the hour from.  But for the splitting into columns, I would use Case statements like follows.  I don't know your calculations, but instead of t.Channel, put your formula.  If it needs to be summed, switch from MAX to SUM.  Replace t.Hour with the table where you are getting the hours.

If it doesn't make sense, post your union query and I'll adjust to use cases.

```
SELECT
t.Hour
MAX(CASE WHEN t.System=1 THEN t.Channel END) T1Channel,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.System=1 THEN t.Board END) T1Board,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.System=2 THEN t.Channel END) T2Channel,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.System=2 THEN t.Board END) T2Board,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.System=3 THEN t.Channel END) T3Channel,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.System=3 THEN t.Board END) T3Board
FROM PDWPeriod t
GROUP BY 
t.Hour
```

New query based on yours:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hh, TSTAMP) AS Hour, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN System=1 THEN CHANNEL END) Processed1, 
max(CASE WHEN System=1 THEN [USED] END)as MaxUsed1,
COUNT(CASE WHEN System=2 THEN CHANNEL END) Processed2, 
max(CASE WHEN System=2 THEN [USED] END)as MaxUsed2,
COUNT(CASE WHEN System=3 THEN CHANNEL END) Processed3, 
max(CASE WHEN System=3 THEN [USED] END)as MaxUsed3,
COUNT(CASE WHEN System=4 THEN CHANNEL END) Processed4, 
max(CASE WHEN System=4 THEN [USED] END)as MaxUsed4
FROM [PINELLASLAB].[dbo].[TelematicPhysicalLines] 
WHERE TSTAMP >= '2019-02-27' AND TSTAMP < '2019-02-28' 
AND STATUS <> 'free' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(dd, TSTAMP), DATEPART(hour, TSTAMP)
```

Comment: here is my two query request to fit:SELECT max([SYSTEM]) as IPAPL1, DATEPART(hh, TSTAMP) AS Hour, COUNT(CHANNEL) Processed, max([USED])as MaxUsed
FROM [PINELLASLAB].[dbo].[TelematicPhysicalLines]
WHERE TSTAMP >= '2019-02-27'
 AND TSTAMP < '2019-02-28' 
 AND STATUS <> 'free'
 AND SYSTEM = '1'
GROUP BY DATEPART(dd, TSTAMP), DATEPART(hour, TSTAMP)

UNION ALL

Comment: SELECT max([SYSTEM]) as IPAPL2, DATEPART(hh, TSTAMP) AS Hour, COUNT(CHANNEL) Processed, max([USED])as MaxUsed
FROM [PINELLASLAB].[dbo].[TelematicPhysicalLines]
WHERE TSTAMP >= '2019-02-27'
 AND TSTAMP < '2019-02-28' 
 AND STATUS <> 'free'
 AND SYSTEM = '2'
GROUP BY DATEPART(dd, TSTAMP), DATEPART(hour, TSTAMP)
ORDER By Hour

Comment: I added a query at the bottom of the answer based on your queries.  This should do what you need.

Comment: Beautiful. I might have more questions but this looks like a winner.

Comment: Paul, this is just the ticket. Not sure where I could have gotten anything close to this without you help. Brilliant job. Thanks for your help. Any resource book or web site that could explain how you came to this?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  If this worked, mark the answer accepted.  I don't have any book recommendations--just keep searching online when you find something you don't know how to do, and you'll learn command by command.

Comment: There should be a check box or maybe a gray check next to my answer, and the question should go from gray (unanswered) to green (answered)

Comment: Thank you I Checked it.